# Wav file duration of Windows media player is not same with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

There is one wav file, if using windows media player open it, its duration is 06:15.
But if using ffmpeg convert it to mp3 or using ffprobe check duration, it shows 06:17.
Of course, other players(like vlc) shows 06:17 too.
What I need to do is, using ffmpeg convert it to mp3 with 06:15 duration.

ffmpeg command:

```
ffmpeg -i 1.wav -f mp3 out.mp3
```

Please help me to resolve this problem, Thanks

Comment: Share the full output of `ffmpeg -i 1.wav`

Comment: Your WAV file contains MP3-coded audio,and has apparently no indication of the priming samples at the start of the stream. So ffmpeg is counting that frame when calculating duration. WMP isn't. Simply copy the data over - no need to re-encode: `ffmpeg -i 1.wav -c copy out.mp3`

Comment: Thanks for your comments. If I play it using WMP, its duration is 06:15, and using HTML5 Audio, it's 06:17, it is just the problem what I have to resolve. So I think it must be converted the other format with 06:15 duration. I am still getting same issue with adding -c copy.

Comment: `ffmpeg -i 1.wav -af "atrim=start_frame=1,asetpts-PTS-STARTPTS" out.mp3`

Comment: [Parsed_atrim_0 @ 000002a12ab18c00] Option 'start_frame' not found
[AVFilterGraph @ 000002a12aacafc0] Error initializing filter 'atrim' with args 'start_frame=1'
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Option not found
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:0
Conversion failed!

Comment: `ffmpeg -i 1.wav -af "aselect='not(eq(n\,0))',asetpts-PTS-STARTPTS" out.mp3`

Answer (score 0):

ffmpeg result is below.

```
    ffmpeg version git-2020-05-28-c0f01ea Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
      built with gcc 9.3.1 (GCC) 20200523
      configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libsrt --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --disable-w32threads --enable-libmfx --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt --enable-amf
      libavutil      56. 49.100 / 56. 49.100
      libavcodec     58. 89.100 / 58. 89.100
      libavformat    58. 43.100 / 58. 43.100
      libavdevice    58.  9.103 / 58.  9.103
      libavfilter     7. 83.100 /  7. 83.100
      libswscale      5.  6.101 /  5.  6.101
      libswresample   3.  6.100 /  3.  6.100
      libpostproc    55.  6.100 / 55.  6.100
    Input #0, wav, from '1.wav':
      Duration: 00:06:17.50, bitrate: 63 kb/s
        Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3 (U[0][0][0] / 0x0055), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 64 kb/s
    Stream mapping:
      Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mp3 (mp3float) -> mp3 (mp3_mf))
    Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
    [mp3_mf @ 000002e13cca9100] MFT name: 'MP3 Encoder ACM Wrapper MFT'
    Output #0, mp3, to 'out.mp3':
      Metadata:
        TSSE            : Lavf58.43.100
        Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3 (mp3_mf), 44100 Hz, mono, s16, 128 kb/s
        Metadata:
          encoder         : Lavc58.89.100 mp3_mf
    size=    2816kB time=00:03:14.50 bitrate= 118.6kbits/s speed= 388x    
    size=    5887kB time=00:06:17.54 bitrate= 127.7kbits/s speed= 393x    
    video:0kB audio:5886kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.007665%
```